# FileUtils.rm で * を展開して使う方法

Tags: ruby

特定の文字列をファイル名に含むファイルを一括削除するために

```
FileUtils.rm("/var/foo/something_*")
```

としたんですが、`*`の展開を受け持つのが`rm`ではなくシェルの役目だからだと思いますが`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`になってしまいました。

とりあえずは`Dir.glob`を使って

```
Dir.glob("/var/foo/something_*").each{ |f| FileUtils.rm(f) }
```

で目的の動作は行えたんですが、`FileUtils.rm`コマンド単体で`*`の展開を行うことはできますか？

もしくはそれ以外でシンプルに書ける方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ドキュメント](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm)を見てもワイルドカード展開ができるようには書いていないので、「`FileUtils.rm`コマンド単体で`*`の展開を行うこと」については無理だと思います。

第１引数の`list`には、複数のファイルパスをまとめて渡せるので、

```
FileUtils.rm(Dir.glob("/var/foo/something_*"))
```

と書けば、(場合によっては、`FileUtils.rm Dir.glob("/var/foo/something_*")`)少しだけ短くなりますが。

Comment: やはり `glob`で展開をしてから渡すしかないんですね。複数の引数を取れることは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。